# How to get thumbnail from a live camera or a NSURL

Tags: iphone

I want to know that Can we get thumbnails from a live camera or video? If yes then how? Please suggest me what is best way to show more then 20 or 30 live cameras in a UITableView. I have customized the UITableViewCell and added a UIWebView to that cell with the loadRequest. But this is much slower and also got unvisitable on table scroll. How I can get out of these problems.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can get the data stream from the camera, find how to make an image with that stream and then create an NSOperation to load asynchronously each image view in every visible cell.

To make a table view slick you need to use dequeueing of table view cells. You should also keep track of which cells are being displayed, which ones are going to be (when scrolled) and which ones won't be visible any more, to manage the loading/unloading of the thumbnails.

Bare in mind that you should get the original stream, scale it, then store it. Otherwise you will waste memory storing a big picture that is being downscaled to be shown as a thumbnail.

I hope this brings up some ideas. best of luck